# How to determine the giver Steam profile / id on a gifted item?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The [Gift Wrap](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gift_wrap) is a Team Fortress 2 item that can be used on another item.  When unwrapped, it adds a "Gift from: " description to the wrapped item.  However, Steam names are not unique, whereas ID's are.  Is there any way to find the original gift giver?

Possible motivations include:

- verifying authenticity, as gift wraps are often used to "autograph" / sign items
- idle curiosity, as although items can change hands many times, the gift description is permanent unless overwritten by another gift wrap.

Comment: I dont think there is a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of finding it out without looking at the history. Firstly, you can choose to look into the API. If you have an API Key (Very quick to get) Just browse the link below from the domain you choose and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the gifters name and their steam ID is just below.

http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?language=en&SteamID=`<Steam ID here>`&key=`<API Key here>`

Alternatively, you can use one of the backpack viewers that allow you too see the gifter. I personally haven't looked that much. *Backpack.tf* doesn't have it and nor does *tf2items*.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I've revised this answer, as the original was wrong.

Yes, you can view the profile of an item gifted to you. The trouble is, most backpack viewers don't provide this capability yet, so you've got to use the right one.

[tf2b.com](http://tf2b.com) is a backpack viewer that has this functionality:

1. Enter your profile ID or sign in through Steam
2. Click the Team Fortress 2 category
3. Locate the item in your backpack you'd like to check the recipient from
4. Click on it, then click 'Item Page'
5. The link to the gifter is in the lower right corner.

Matthew's backpack viewer and sending your own API calls can obtain this information as well, however it is already covered above.

Comment: Apparently if tf2b.com knows about your item's history it gives you a direct link to the giver / crafter's backpack.  If it doesn't know about it you get sent to a 404 page.  Here's the [Skull Island Topper](http://tf2b.com/tf2/item/lavabenny/1215631279) and here's the [Haunted Rump-o'-Lantern](http://tf2b.com/tf2/item/gigazelle/1209963579).  Incidentally, tf2b.com can correctly find the original giver of both items.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks, I've revised my answer to reflect that information.